# How to append 2 default values to a JSONB column in Postgres SQL 14?

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-14, jsonb

Previously I had 4 default values for a jsonb column in my table cities.

```
create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
  
  t.jsonb    "config",          default: {"A"=>5, "B"=>7, "C"=>10, "D"=>10}
```

Now I want to add 2 more default values `"E"=10` and `"F"=0` to this column without changing the values of A,B,C and D. Note that the values of A,B,C and D have been updated differently for different cities. So I just want to append the default values of E and F to the column without changing the existing ones of A,B,C and D.

I cant't quite figure out the UPDATE query for this. I am quite new to this so its a little confusing. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Table definitions should be shown as `CREATE TABLE` statements, not some fancy different syntax that has nothing to do with SQL

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me if you are trying to change the default value of the column, or if you want to update existing rows in the table.

If you want to update the rows in the table, use an UPDATE statement with the concatenation operator `||`:

```
update cities
  set config = config||'{"E": 10, "F": 0}'
where ...
```

Comment: I am actually trying to add 2 more default values to the column apart from the 4 already present.

Comment: @Priyanshu0007: then the UPDATE should do what you want.